# What is the default document size we can upload in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: file-upload

What is the default document size we can upload in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default size is 50MB.  That can be changed in Central Admin via Web Application Settings --> General Settings.